# JavaScript - DOM Selector Engine

Tags: javascript, selector

Is there any selector engine for DOM elements like jQuery which offers no other extended methods like `.bind`, `.css` etc? What I mean is, a selector which just return found elements, nothing more. I tried to modify the jQuery, removed methods to get only the function that returns elements, but I got errors.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at sizzle -

http://sizzlejs.com/

I believe it is the selector engine that jQuery uses.

Comment: The web site states only 4KB when minified and gzipped

Answer (score 1):

If you code is intended to work only in modern browsers and the set of possible selectors is relatively simple (`A.classA B.classB` or something) you can use `document.querySelectorAll` with a thin wrapper over it or even do not use any frameworks at all.

As for old browsers, well, you always can try to implement it yourself, if size is so crucial for you. You can choose a tiny set of simple CSS selectors and use only them.

But, as well ipr101, I guess it will be better to use production-ready solution like sizzle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many tiny JavaScript selector engines, like:

- [Quicksand](http://quicksand.joijs.com/)
- [Qwery](https://github.com/ded/qwery)
- [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)
- [Slick](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Slick/Slick)
- [uSelector](https://github.com/fabiomcosta/micro-selector/)
- [Zest](https://github.com/chjj/zest)

I'd recommend **Quicksand**, because it seems to be the fastest one (see [this](http://jsperf.com/selector-engine-speed-test-quicksand-vs-jquery-vs-qwery) or [this](http://quicksand.joijs.com/test/) test).